# Where is the Class Model in Xcode 4?

Tags: objective-c, workspace, xcode4

Anyone knows where the hell are the Class Models in Xcode 4?
Or the Xcode 4 GM seed doesn't implemented this feature yet?

I'm going crazy with this!

In Xcode 3 was so simple. Design -> Class Model -> Quick Model!
But now in Xcode 4...  God Dammit!

So, anyone knows?

Comment: As Xcode4 is still under an NDA you might get a better answer on the developer forums.

Comment: Did you find any way for class modeling in Xcode 4?

Comment: I must be in the extreme minority here since I'd like the answer as well.  Apparently it has been removed in XCode 4.

Comment: Why on earth this question got closed is beyond me. I'm a visitor from the future and I would've liked seeing an answer to it.