# Where is the Class Model in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

This was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045714/where-is-the-class-model-in-xcode-4) but that was a beta XCode. Now with official xcode 4, I don't found how to create the Class Model. In XCode 3 this is very easy and obvious: File->New File->Class Model document template in 'others'.

Anyway, the main question is: There are Class Model in XCode 4?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no class model in Xcode 4. The class modeling tool was eliminated in Xcode 4.

Comment: That's not to say it won't come back but it was apparently deemed unpopular enough to be safely left out for now at the very least. I base this on a number of responses from the Xcode Tools team in Apple's developer forums where they're careful to guard against "yeah, [feature] is gone and isn't coming back."

Comment: Where I can see this Apple developer forum, and how I know this is by XCode Tools team. I already see this list mail: http://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/xcode-users

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the above anwser is correct, even though you can still find references to [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XCodeDesignTools/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006858-SW1).

I needed this to help me analyse an existing project that I'll have to maintain and I found [Autograf](http://autograf.sourceforge.net/). Even though it seems not to be actively maintained it still works.

Comment: The last update was 7 year later. Because this will not have things like blocks. But if you will maintain it, good luck. :)

Comment: And that's the end of Autograf. Doesn't work anymore on Lion, because of the dropped support for PowerPC.